# Digital Ocean Database Issue related to MyISAM

Tags: mysql, digital-ocean, myisam

Our Laravel app uses InnoDB as well as MyISAM tables and it was working fine until recently the Servers have been moved to Digital Ocean in order to use their "Distributed Database System".

Now when I run the migrations, it works fine until it finds the first table migration which tries to create MyISAM table and script crashes giving following error:

```
Storage engine MyISAM is disabled (Table creation is disallowed)
```

Could anyone tell me how can I ENABLE the Storage engine MyISAM in Digital Ocean?

I searched a lot and couldn't find any useful thread.

======

#### UPDATE

Most of the comments suggest that I should just switch to InnoDB which is going to be the ultimate solution but IF there is any way to enable MyISAM storage engine for digital ocean, I would like to know that.

Comment: Any reason you can't just switch the tables to InnoDB? It's a much better engine anyway. That's probably why myISAM is switched off - it's c**p! It hasn't been the default in mySQL for quite a long time now

Comment: I know...but there is this one table where we store a lots of JSON data in various TEXT datatype columns..and if you have many text datatype columns in your table...i think MyISAM works better for the particular case scenario than InooDB so was just curious if its possible

Comment: *".i think MyISAM works better for the particular case scenario than InooDB so was just curious if its possible "*.. stop using MyISAM, MyISAM is on its way to deprecation also a correctly configured InnoDB outperforms MyISAM by miles..

Comment: Why do i think MyISAM is on its way to deprecation?  The manual has a hint which on which i based it on -> *"In MySQL 8.0.16 and later, on-disk internal temporary tables always use the InnoDB storage engine; as of MySQL 8.0.16, this variable has been removed and is thus no longer supported.
"* [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine)

Comment: *"IF there is any way to enable MyISAM storage engine for digital ocean, I would like to know that."* ->  Ideally you should ask [them](https://www.digitalocean.com/support/) not us?

Comment: *"if you can confirm that you are talking on behalf of the whole StackOverflow community and no one knows the answer."* Fair enough, the *"Storage engine MyISAM is disabled (Table creation is disallowed)"* error is based on Server configuration, the only one that can change or allow that is digital ocean..

Comment: Well maybe someone has used that host and tried that specific thing. So maybe someone will come along who knows. But it's fairly likely that the people who actually work there and control those servers will be able to tell you quicker. We can quickly answer questions about the technology in general, but it's a lot less likely that we'll know the specifics of a particular proprietary platform unless we happen to have used it ourselves. And given the vast number of internet hosts out there and your relatively niche information request, the odds probably aren't all that good...

Comment: And as Raymond says, you'll still probably end up having to contact them to actually carry out the task anyway. I doubt you have permission to do that, unless it's a private VPS on which you can install anything you like. On any kind of shared or "cloud" hosting, you'll be a lot more restricted, since others will also be using the same platform. Note also that there's a good chance they switched it off for a reason and might simply refuse to enable it again

Comment: @ADyson I have submitted a ticket. I will see what they say and will also update or close this question accordingly. Fingers crossed..maybe help will come here or there

Comment: if you get a answer on your ticket, please post that answer here as reference for the future

Comment: @RaymondNijland will do

Comment: Check to see if Digital Ocean is using Galera or InnoDB Cluster.  Clustering does not allow the use of MyISAM (or the Query Cache).  Meanwhile, here are some tips on conversion to InnoDB:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

Comment: I have the same issue, I have a fragile and very large backup that needs to be converted but I don't know how to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone wondering the same thing here. It is simply not possible. There is nothing MyISAM provides in plus which you cant do with InnoDB so the only way is to convert your MyISAM migrations to InnoDB. Also in my case, we are using managed DB which for sure does not support MyISAM in the digital ocean.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you change sql as below:

```sql
--incorrect create table sql：
CREATE TABLE t (i INT) ENGINE = MYISAM;
--new creat table sql(amended)：
CREATE TABLE t (i INT) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Another way to resolve the issue but it's NOT suggestion to do it by the way：

1、check current engine of database

```sql
show engines;
```

2、check current table engine

Two way to check：

```sql
show table status from `db_name` where name='table_name';
--or
show create table table_name;
```

3、modify the current engine

```sql
alter table table_name engine=innodb;
```

4、close `InnoDB` engine

close mysql service：

```sh
net stop mysql
```

find the installation folder of MySQL, and open the file`my.ini`：

change from `default-storage-engine=INNODB` to `default-storage-engine=MYISAM`

change from `#skip-innodb` to `skip-innodb`

start mysql service：

```sh
net start mysql
```

Comment: the reference link:https://bluetata.blog.csdn.net/article/details/120995180