# MySql / PHP - General error: 3161 Storage engine MyISAM is disabled

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, digital-ocean

So, I have a set up where I am using a remote database server that digital ocean provides and a server hosting a PHP application. Both on the same network, so connection appears to be fine. I am getting the below error when trying to set up the database.

```
General error: 3161 Storage engine MyISAM is disabled (Table creation is disallowed). (SQL: create table `flrm_posts` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `discussion_id` int unsigned not null, `number` int unsigned null, `time` datetime not null, `user_id` int unsigned null, `type` varchar(100) null, `content` text null, `edit_time` datetime null, `edit_user_id` int unsigned null, `hide_time` datetime null, `hide_user_id` int unsigned null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' engine = MyISAM)
```

I am aware that it states `engine = MyISAM`so I am assuming that it is trying to use that engine when making the request. I have also run the `SHOW ENGINES;` query on my server. It returned the following:

```
+--------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             ------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine             | Support | Comment                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+--------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             ------------+--------------+------+------------+
| MRG_MYISAM         | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                                                                                                                                                                                   | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM             | YES     | MyISAM storage engine                                                                                                                                                                                                   | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | Performance Schema                                                                                                                                                                                                      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| InnoDB             | DEFAULT | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and f                                                                                                                                                             oreign keys | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| MEMORY             | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for tempor                                                                                                                                                             ary tables  | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV                | YES     | CSV storage engine                                                                                                                                                                                                      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+--------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                             ------------+--------------+------+------------+
```

How do I resolve this issue? I know that I could set the Engine to use MyISAM but I have seen a few articles floating about saying that this will have performance issues?

Any help and feedback would be massively appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58711584/digital-ocean-database-issue-related-to-myisam may be worth a read.

Comment: I've had a look, still not solved my issues. I have also checked the php file that handles setting the engine and it has this line of` code ' engine'    => 'InnoDB', ` so it appears to be setting it correctly. Also, database seems to be using InnoDB as well

Comment: Change your application to ask for and use `InnoDB`.  Don't fight it; MyISAM is going away.

Comment: @RickJames it already is trying to use it

Comment: Hmmm:  `flrm_posts ... engine=MyISAM`

Comment: If your database(MySQL) is 8.0 or above, you should be use `InnoDB`, you can use`SELECT VERSION()` to see your databases version.